# Is there any way to dynamically retrieve data to Android spinner from MySQL database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-spinner, android-adapter

I have two tables in the MySQL database:

```
Country(country_id,country_name)

City(city_id,city_name,country_id)
```

I want to retrieve country table data in a spinner and according cities in city table. I searched on the web but no help found anywhere.

I am using PHP web service as back end to retrive and store data from database. I only know about binding drop down items in spinner using `ArrayList` and `list` interface methods like `list.add()` etc..

Can any one guide me what to do? I don't need the code. But, someone plz guide me in which way we can do this?

Comment: So you have two spinners one for Country and other for Cities?? and all you want to do is when your select country from Country Spinner , you automatically want to populate corresponding cities to Cities  Spinner??

Comment: My suggestion is use a hashmap to store cityname & country_id .., so that you can retrieve it as per your need.

Comment: @MukeshRana Yes, I have two spinners and exactly, I want to populate corresponding cities to Cities Spinner.

Comment: @Naufal Did you mean HashMap data structure? But, What would if I want to change country or city details after deploying application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as per your needs, all you have to do is First of all, Load Countries name and their corresponding ids from your Countries Table in database into an ArrayList of custom object(containing country name and country id).From that ArrayList of custom objects, you have to make an array of Country names and bind that to your Country Spinner. When one of the Country in your spinner is selected, you will save that index and look for country id at same index in ArrayList of custom objects. once you get the Country Id, you simply have a select query in your Cities Table with where clause and you can get from there an ArrayList of City Names and populate that list into your cities Spinner.

Your Custom Object Class will look like this

```
public class CountryInfoBean {

    private String countryName = "";
    private String countryId = "";



public String getCountryName() {
    return countryName;
}

public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
    this.countryName = countryName;
}

public String getCountryId() {
    return countryId;
}

public void setCountryId(String countryId) {
    this.countryId = countryId;
}
}
```

and ArrayList of Custom Objects will be something like this

```
ArrayList<CountryInfoBean> countriesList=new ArrayList<CountryInfoBean>();
```

Comment: "When one of the Country in your spinner is selected, you will save that index and look for country id at same index in ArrayList of custom objects." So, the ArrayList of custom objects will have the parsed JSON response objects from country table?

Comment: No no that is not a JSON Response.You have to make a Class say CountryInfoBean in which you have two variables countryName and countryId with their getter and setters and your arrayList will look like this ArrayList<CountryInfoBean>. So when you will be fetching Country Name and id from your database you have to create an object of CountryInfoBean and set countryName and countryId and put that object into this ArrayList<CountryInfoBean>.